# Using By in POM - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, testng, abstract-class

I have been practicing using POM design approach (with Data Driven & testNg framework) for Selenium;

I recently got to see a selenium automation developer using POM with neither @FindBy nor PageFactory in the script

What I didn't understand using 'By' in the selenium script as follows:

```
By element_name = By.id("String");
```

'By' is an abstract class (as mentioned in selenium -- java api documentation), and the methods such id, classname, name, xpath and etc  are static methods;

Based on these facts, how is the abstract class and static methods are directly implemented?

Below is the code I am talking about.

```
public TrialLoginPage(WebDriver driver, Properties prop) {

     super(driver, prop);

    }

    By name = By.name("username");
    By password = By.name("password");
    By submit = By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']");

    public String getTitle() {

        String title = driver.getTitle();
        return title;
    }

    public WebElement setUserName() {

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(name);

        return element;
    }

    public WebElement setPassword() {

        WebElement element = driver.findElement(password);
        return element;
    }

    public WebElement setSubmit() {

        WebElement login = driver.findElement(submit);
        return login;
    }

    public String driverStatus() {

        String str = driver.toString();
        return str;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[By](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) is an [abstract class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html), it can have methods with implementation, the only restriction for abstract is that it can't be instantiated, e.g. calling `new By()`

> it may or may not include abstract methods. Abstract classes cannot be instantiated

You are calling `name` method which isn't abstract that returns `By` object:

> ```
> public static By name(java.lang.String name)
> ```

Comment: Thank you for friends for helping me to understand the query!